# How can I use variable for jquery validation equalTo method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

I want to use variable for jquery validation equalTo method. But not working for jquery selector. How can I do this?

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="pass1" id="passM" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="pass2" id="passR" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var form = $('#form'),
    el1  = '#'+form.find('#passM').attr('id'),
    el2  = form.find('#passR').attr('name');


form.validate({

    rules: {

          el2: {
            equalTo: el1
        }
    }
})
```

**<kbd>[Code example](http://jsfiddle.net/nj5uC/2/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
var form = $('#form'),
    el1  = '#'+form.find('#passM').attr('id'),
    el2  = form.find('#passR').attr('name');

var r = {};
r[el2] = { equalTo: el1 };

form.validate({
    rules: r
});
```

Comment: Right! Sorry about that. Edited.

Comment: Just keep on adding to the _r_ object. e.g. r[ elM ] = { equalTo: elN };